# How to implement create event feature like the one in iPhone/iPad calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, calendar, touch-event

I will implement a calendar application for iPad and I want the user to be able to create an event with almost the same experience as the native calendar app. (I took the images from iPhone but it's almost the same in iPad).

---

I have 3 questions:

1. As seen in the picture, to create an event the user does a long press on the day view. When he does this, there pops the purple rectangle with handles on it. To implement this by myself, will I create a UIView and add this to my view controller's view as a subview, above the table view that scrolls the hours below?
2. To make this event's rectangle longer, the user drags it from its handles. To implement this, will I override touchesMoved, etc... methods of the UIView I created?
3. To move this event between the hours, the user drags the rectangle up and down. My question here is that, when the UIView is dragged to the topmost, how will I scroll the tableview of the hours, so that the user is able to drag the event further to the top?

If you have any other recommendations, I'll be glad to hear them. Thx

[image]
[image]